# Spring kafka: What’s the relationship b/w concurrency we set and listeners?

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory like this:

```
@Bean
KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(40);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(3000);
        return factory;
      }
```

I also have multiple listeners for specific topics:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "id1", topicPattern  =  "test1.*")
      public void listenTopic1(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        System.out.println("Topic: " + record.topic());
      }

@KafkaListener(id = "id2", topicPattern  =  "test2.*")
      public void listenTopic2(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
        System.out.println("Topic: " + record.topic());
      }
```

The concurrency I'm setting, is it specific to a listener or all listeners? Note: All topics have 40 partitions.

Some topics have more load than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Each container will get 40 consumer threads. The factory creates a container for each listener, with the same properties.

Your topic will need at least 40 partitions for this to be effective since a partition can only be consumed by one consumer in a group.

Comment: Yes, all topics have 40 partitions. Can you provide some tips on how we can increase consumer performance? Like I mentioned, some topics have way too much load than the rest. Would it be a good idea to have 2 listeners for the same topic and divide the partitions?

Comment: It won't make any difference; 2 containers with 20 consumers each is functionally identical to 1 container with 40 consumers; you need to profile your listener code to see where the bottlenecks are. Perhaps there are some synchronized blocks, with significant work, which effectively defeat any concurrency. Taking a thread dump with jstack might give you some early clues.

Comment: Thanks for that! Also, I read that during rebalancing, there might be a problem of duplicate records. Does Kafka Spring handle deduplication in any manner?

Comment: The admins here don't like new questions in comments; you should ask a new question. The framework provides a strategy see [Filtering Messages](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#_filtering_messages), but you have to provide the implementation.